# Why dragging an object via touch on mobile teleports it to touch position instead of moving by offset between last touch and current touch?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch

so this is what doesn't make sense to me. A game object (map) is supposed to be moved by the difference between the last touch position and the current touch position. It changes its position to every now touch position first but moves as it's supposed to after. It teleports. I want it to just move by the offset. It works perfectly with mouse input on the PC, so that's why it's confusing me. Been a while since I coded, so it'll probably be something stupid. Here is some code:

```
        if (touch)
        {
            int nbTouches = Input.touchCount;

            if (nbTouches > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nbTouches; i++)
                {
                    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);

                    TouchPhase phase = touch.phase;


                    switch (phase)
                    {
                        case TouchPhase.Began:
                            timeTouched = Time.time;
                            touchPos = touch.position;
                            if (G.mapIsOn)
                            {
                                if (!holding)
                                {
                                    holding = true;
                                    Vector3 touchDownPos = touchPos;
                                    touchDownPos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
                                  //  touchDownPos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane - MapController.MC.mapBackground.transform.position.z;
                                    touchDownPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchDownPos);
                                    lastTouchPos = touchDownPos;
                                }

                            }
                            break;
                        case TouchPhase.Moved:
                            if (G.mapIsOn && holding)
                            {
                                Vector3 newPos = touch.position;
                                newPos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
                            //    newPos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane - MapController.MC.mapBackground.transform.position.z;
                                newPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(newPos);

                         //       if (lastTouchPos != newPos)
                         //       {
                                    if (onHoldMove != null)
                                    {
                                        onHoldMove(newPos, lastTouchPos);
                                    }
                        //        }
                               /* if (onHoldMoveDelta != null)
                                {
                                    onHoldMoveDelta(touch.deltaPosition);
                                }*/

                                //     mapBackground.transform.position = newMapPos;
                                lastTouchPos = newPos;
                            //    lines.ScaleLines();
                                //  Debug.Log("Moving: " + newPos);
                            }
                            //   print("Touch index " + touch.fingerId + " has moved by " + touch.deltaPosition);
                            break;
                        case TouchPhase.Stationary:
                            //   print("Touch index " + touch.fingerId + " is stationary at position " + touch.position);
                            break;
                        case TouchPhase.Ended:
                         //   if (G.mapIsOn)
                       //     {
                                if (holding) holding = false;
                       //     }
                            if (Time.time - timeTouched <= tapTime)
                            {
                                tapped = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case TouchPhase.Canceled:
                            //   print("Touch index " + touch.fingerId + " cancelled");
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

Sorry if the formatting is off. Also sorry for too many commented lines, you can see I've been trying many different "fixes".

```
    public void HandleOnHoldMove(Vector3 newPos, Vector3 lastPos)
    {
        Vector3 offset = lastPos - newPos;
        Vector3 mapPos = mapBackground.transform.position;
        Vector3 newMapPos = new Vector3(mapPos.x - offset.x * mapDragBoost, mapPos.y - offset.y * mapDragBoost, mapPos.z);
        mapBackground.transform.position = newMapPos;
        lines.ScaleLines();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I expected it was something stupid, a missplaced bracket for my mouse input. Touch and mouse were both used as input. Mouse acts as touch input for some reason in unity and I forgot to enclose the map moving code for mouse input from my touch controller. Will delete this question soon, in case anybody is baffeled why is this code not working..

Answer (score 0):

touch input changes the position instantly.
for example, your mouse can't go off the screan, but w ur finger on a touch device u can.

try to use Vector3.Lerp to make a smooth transition between the old and new position, that should work

```
transform.position = Vector3.lerp(transform.position, //New position, //move speed);
```